# How to detect if the iphone is synced when app is not running

Tags: iphone, objective-c, synchronization, mpmusicplayercontroller

I would like to know if there is any way to detect if the iphone music library has changed when my app is not running.

There is a property lastModifiedDate in MPMediaLibrary class which does this but the problem i am facing is that this date changes even if the iPhone is not synced. The date generally changes if the now playing list or current playing list is changed in iPod.

Is there any other way to detect if the iPhone is synced?

Comment: Plus i am not completely sure when the lastModifiedDate is changing apart from change in current pLaying list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the lastModifiedDate and when the application is closed record the status of the playlists and then when the app is opened and the lastModifiedDate has changed: compare the current and previous playlists.

Comment: HI Alex, Thanx for reply. The problem arises even if the now playing list or current playing list is changed in iPod and there is now way to get the current playing list of the iPod (if there is, please let me know!). By your method, i can store the previous playlist(coz the  playlist is set my app while it exists) but cant get the current playlist for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If a device sync with iTunes, it will clear the tmp folder under all apps.
Therefore you may create a blank file in tmp, and next time when your application launch and found the file is missing, the device should have been synced.
To obtain the tmp folder path, use [NSTemporaryDirectory()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW6)

Comment: Thanks @Owen, will check it out today

Comment: HI, again. I hv tried this way but the file in temp dir is not deleted when iphone is synced. I am testing in iOS 3.1.3

Comment: I found that a few years ago, at that time I accidentally used NSTemporaryDirectory() instead of NSHomeDirectory() and a save file ended up saved in <app folder>/tmp/Documents/ instead of <app folder>/Documents/, which cause the save file deleted every time I sync the device. That was a bug that I spent over a week on so I am quite sure on this. Maybe Apple changed this behavior later on.

Comment: As of iOS 8 this method does not work. Any other suggestions?